# Linear homeomorphism of $E \bigoplus F$ to $E \bigoplus F'$ implies linear homeomorphism of $F$ to $F'$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

If all the following spaces are banach spaces, then the existence of a linearhomeomorphism of $E \bigoplus F$ to $E \bigoplus F'$ implies on the existence of a linear homeomorphism of $F$ to $F'$?

I'm trying to argue this is true to complete a prove, but i'm not able to do it.

One thing that i'm trying to do to advance on this is prove that if $\phi$ is the linear homemorphism, and $a \in E$, $b \in F$, then $\phi(a) \in E$ and $\phi(b) \in F'$, but i'm not even sure that this is true.
Any hints would be helpful!

Comment: I think $\phi(a)\in E$ is not true, so that approach does not work or has to be modified.

Answer (score 2):

This not true, let $E$ be a separable infinite dimensional  Hilbert space  and $F,F'$ finite dimensional, $E\oplus F$ is isomorphic to $E\oplus F'$.

Comment: I think this is wrong, because both are isomorphic to some $\Bbb R^n$

Comment: @supinf this is exactly why the answer is correct in its assertion.

Comment: @Tyrone but in order to disprove the claim in the question, don't we need to show that $F$ and $F'$ are not isomorphic?

Comment: @supinf they don't need to be isomorphic to the *same* $\mathbb{R}^n$. *Each* is isomorphic to some finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}^n$. i.e. $E\oplus \mathbb{R}^n\cong E\oplus \mathbb{R}^m$ is a separable real hilbert space so is just $\ell_2$.

Comment: @Tyrone I see what you mean (it was not mentioned in the answer that $F,F'$ are supposed to have different dimension). But the dual space $F'$ of a finite dimensional space $F$ has always the same dimension as $F$, so I remain unconvinced.

Comment: @supinf I see what *you* mean. I was assuming that $F'$ was a just second Banach space  (and not necessarily the dual of $F$). I think the op should clarify which is the case...

Comment: In the question F' is just another banach space